# Replacing Singular Values of a Matrix with Complex Ones

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

Is there a procedure to replace singular values of a real valued matrix according to:

s1 -> i*s1

s2 -> i*s2

...

without going through any singular value decomposition (change singular values and repack) or any similar costly procedure?

Thanks

Comment: The singular values of a matrix are, by definition, real and non-negative. So you'll not find a matrix with complex singular values anyway…

Comment: Thanks Dirk. What about eigenvalues of a positive semi definite matrix? Can I replace them with complex counterparts without finding the eigenvalues first?

Comment: Sure, multiple by $i$.

Answer (score 1):

The SVD of $A=U\Sigma V^{\star}$.
Your matrix is $\Sigma^{\prime}=i\Sigma$. Then you can just write
$$
A=-iU\Sigma^{\prime}V^{\star}.
$$